# Changing Carbon object date format to be used for query

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a table that consists of a column named `created_at`. Whenever I dump this specific column, it returns as a Carbon object as below:
[image]

I've coded this query to get data from the said table based on date. Code is as below:

```
$date = $this->request->get('date');
$orders = Order::where( 'created_at', $date )->get();
```

`$date` is retrieved from the url and the format is `'Y-m-d'` making it impossible to query properly since `'created_at'` and `$date` is not in the same format. How can I get date from the Carbon object in `'Y-m-d'` format and insert it in my query?

Comment: You need to understand that the field `created_at` is just a DateTime format in the database. The model class has mutators in place for date fields that instantiate the Carbon object on it. and that is what you are getting https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: No worries @Kotzilla has solved the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if `$date` is in format `Y-m-d` you can use `whereDate` like this

```
$orders = Order::whereDate( 'created_at', $date )->get();
```

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about `whereDate()`. This solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful of your timezone. If the date is stored as Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, this date will be irrelevant for a user querying it in San Francisco. For a proper worldwide support, you should store UTC date-time in your DB and consider a day is the 24-hours period from midnight in the user timezone.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
$date = $date->toDateString();
```

Or just

```
$date = $date->format("Y-m-d");
```